# Need Date Format Assistance

Tags: sql, date, format

I am trying to compare the default date in SQL table to getdate() to perform a comparison.  What date format should I use for date_expired?

Example:

```
date_expired = '2015-02-15 00:00:00.000'
```

I need to compare this to getdate().

When using

```
date_expired > get_date
```

the record is not showing up.

When using

```
'2015-02-15 00:00:00.000' > convert(CHAR(10), getdate(), 101).
```

The record displays correctly.

Thanks in advance,

Greg

Comment: Run the Command: `SELECT GetDate()` this should show you the format to compare against.

Comment: Can you provide the exact query you're running? Maybe then we can provide more assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is. When I run the below code, it returns true:

```
DECLARE @date_expired VARCHAR(MAX) = '2017-02-15 00:00:00.000'

IF @date_expired > GetDate()
    SELECT 'true'
ELSE
    SELECT 'false'
```

Comment: The date is 2015-02-15 00:00:00.000.  It does return false with the correct year, however, the date is not a variable.  It is stored in a table.  (sorry for the confusion).  So the value for date_expired is 2015-02-15 00:00:00.000.   Whenever I use date_expired > getdate() the result set is empty even though the date_expired value is 2015-02-15 00:00:00.000 in the result set.